# Can I get Linked Account Name in AWS Cost Explorer API call?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Using this code snippet:

```py
def get_cost_and_usage_data(start, end):

    ce_obj = boto3.client('ce')
    data = ce_obj.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={'Start':start, 'End':end},
        Granularity='MONTHLY', #MONTHLY, DAILY, HOURLY
        Metrics=['BLENDED_COST', 'UNBLENDED_COST', 'AMORTIZED_COST'],
        GroupBy=[{'Type':'DIMENSION', 'Key':'LINKED_ACCOUNT'},  {'Type':'DIMENSION', 'Key':'SERVICE'}]
    )
```

Is it possible to get the linked account name together with the linked account ID without using the `describe-account` method in the AWS Organizations API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to describe account api as it requires accountid to describe it. Although if you use listaccounts. it will give you all the accounts details(with name and id). Please refer to below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccounts.html

Thanks

Ashish

Comment: figured as much, I actually just tried to use listaccounts. Thank you for answering!